# I am getting an error when loading my app

Tags: heroku, deployment

When I deploy the application using pipeline, status is showing deployment successful and build successful. After that, it shows an error in the homepage. After loading, refreshing the page resolves the issue and the homepage is displayed. It is intermediate. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

how are you doing today! I got what you meant by status is showing deployment successful and build successful. After that, it shows an error in the homepage. After loading, refreshing the page resolves the issue and the homepage is displayed. It is intermediate. The reason is very simple we just have to do somethings and everything will come to normal

Comment: What kind of things are you going to do?

Comment: Hi,

1. Do you have Linksys Router/adaptor connected to the computer?
2. How long have you been facing this issue?
3. Did you make any changes on the computer prior to this issue?

Step 1: If you have Linksys router/adaptor connected to the computer then update the driver for that device and check.   I can do this for you if you don't get it